# About the tutorial on Setting up your robot using tf

Tags: ros, catkin-make, broadcaster, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the tutorial here => wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF on the TF (sorry my karma doesn't allow me to post link) and I had those lines at the end of the make file

```
add_executable(tf_broadcaster src/tf_broadcaster.cpp)
add_executable(tf_listener src/tf_listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tf_broadcaster ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(tf_listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Then I used catkin_make that compile without a problem but when I use

```
rosrun robot_setup_tf tf_broadcaster
```

I have in my terminal this

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named tf_broadcaster below /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/robot_setup_tf
```

After a few search it appears that the file is actually situated here

```
/home/ros/catkin_ws/devel/lib/robot_setup_tf
```

I can launch it manually and it's working perfectly, it just that I can't understand why it's there and not in the src folder of the robot_setup_tf. If someone could explain to me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137566/about-the-tutorial-on-setting-up-your-robot-using-tf/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin does out-of-source builds, so the location of your executable is absolutely correct.

The actual strange thing is why rosrun searches your node in your source directory.
Did you try re-sourcing setup.bash?

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-09**:
I tried "source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash" without much success. Nor wth the setup.bash in the devel of my catkin directory.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-09**:
The one in the devel directory of your catkin workspace is the right one to source. I get the same error when I try to run an executable that does not exist. (also with ~/catkin_ws/src/...)

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-09**:
Yep it did the trick. Should I put this source in the .bashrc ?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-10**:
Yes you can add this to your .bashrc. This will save you from some future headache.